# how to set launcher icons to 7 and 10 inches tablet in android

Tags: android, drawable, tablet

I'm looking at how to set launcher icons for 7 inch and 10 inch tablet. Gone through many articles and but no luck. I have tried with drawable-sw600dp-mdpi and etc.. But none of them seems to work on my tablet. The launcher icon seems to be very small in these devices. I want the icon should look bigger in these devices. any help would be appreciated. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Try using launcher icon generator

[Go to this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

[image]

And upload your icon and download the file

You will get a res folder.Copy this res folder to your projects app/src/main folder where another res folder reside,override this folder.

This will solve your problem since this app generate icons of several resolution and stores it in appropriate folder